# Understanding unexpected behavior in my code

Tags: c++, pointers, object, persistence

I have been trying to persist an object by writing to a file and reading it later, but I could not get it working. Some one help me understand my mistake ?

**

```
while (c < m_size) {
        // Either tmp or *tmp gives null, but has valid value in debugger, don't know what I am doing wrong here :(
        std::cout << c << " byte = " << *tmp << std::endl;
        tmp++; c++;
    }
    // File is empty either if use tmp or (char*) this
    out.write(tmp, m_size);
```

**

This is my code based on an example I read somewhere else.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Persistent
{
public:
    Persistent(int x, int y) : m_size(sizeof(*this)), m_x(x), m_y(y)
    {
        
    }
    void read(std::ifstream& in);
    void write(std::ofstream& out);
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "X = " << m_x << " Y = " << m_y << std::endl;
    }
    
private:
    size_t m_size;
    int m_x, m_y;
};

void Persistent::read(std::ifstream& in)
{
    in.read((char*)this, m_size);
}

void Persistent::write(std::ofstream& out)
{
    char *tmp = (char*)this;
    int c = 0;
    while (c < m_size) {
        // Either tmp or *tmp gives null, but has valid value in debugger, don't know what I am doing wrong here :(
        std::cout << c << " byte = " << *tmp << std::endl;
        tmp++; c++;
    }
    // File is empty either if use tmp or (char*) this
    out.write(tmp, m_size);
}

int main()
{
    Persistent p1(5, 8);
    
    // Write object to File
    std::ofstream out("MyObject.dat");
    p1.write(out);
    
    Persistent p2(0,0);
    
    // Read object from filee
    std::ifstream in("MyObject.dat");
    p2.read(in);
    p2.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Anyone please ?

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't store just the `m_x` and `m_y`. Also what is the issue? Do you get some error or do you read back wrong values?

Comment: Like i said I am unable to write object bytes to file, and also when I output the object bytes in a loop it does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309552/is-it-acceptable-to-take-the-self-answer-from-an-edit-to-the-question-and-post-i) from [@Dinesh G's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7152961/dinesh-g) original post:

> Sorted out myself. Just need to flush the stream after writing to get it working (as it was not written), and also had to cast bytes to int to see their values as they were interpreted as ASCII before.